# Resize an image along rows only or columns only in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, resize

I'm writing a function in matlab to zoom or shrink an image using bicubic interpolation. However, my function resizes an image along both rows and columns. What if I want to enlarge the image along the rows only, or along the columns only? This is my code so far

```
function pic_new = zoom_image(pic, zoom_value)

actualSize = size(pic);
newSize = max(floor(zoom_value.*actualSize(1:2)),1);

newX = ((1:newSize(2))-0.5)./zoom_value+0.5;  %# New image pixel X coordinates
newY = ((1:newSize(1))-0.5)./zoom_value+0.5;

oldClass = class(pic);  %# Original image type
pic = double(pic);      %# Convert image to double precision for interpolation

if numel(actualSize) == 2
    pic_new = interp2(pic,newX,newY(:),'cubic');
end

pic_new = cast(pic_new,oldClass);

end
```

---

**Updated**: I was able to resize the image both along rows and columns. However, it doesn't work right

This is the original image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/895x383q90/r/903/4jM76I.png

This is the image after being enlarge 2.5 along rows and shrunk 1.3 along columns: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/323x465q90/r/673/EHIaoB.png

Why is there such a black box in the result image?

**Updated 2**: This is how I did: in the command window type

```
>> img = imread('pic.pgm');
>> newImage = zoom_image(img, 2.5, 1/1.3);
>> imshow(newImage)
```

Comment: Enlarge along rows only? Use `newX = 1:actualSize(2)`. Make the guess for columns only?

Comment: Linsk are broken so inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try editing your function to have a separate zoom for rows and columns, a la

```
function pic_new = zoomfunc(pic, zoom_valueX, zoom_valueY)
actualSize = size(pic);
newSize = max(floor([zoom_valueY zoom_valueX].*actualSize(1:2)),1);

newX = ((1:newSize(2))-0.5)./zoom_valueX+0.5;  %# New image pixel X coordinates
newY = ((1:newSize(1))-0.5)./zoom_valueY+0.5;

oldClass = class(pic);  %# Original image type
pic = double(pic);      %# Convert image to double precision for interpolation

if numel(actualSize) == 2
    pic_new = interp2(pic,newX,newY(:),'cubic');
end

pic_new = cast(pic_new,oldClass);

end
```

Comment: I updated my post. Can you please take a look at it? It doesn't work right. Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell without more - could you post a matfile containing the "pic" variable so we can see how it's formatted?  My initial guess is that it's trying to interpolate outside of the range of the picture, so that you have a large space of NaN that just shows up as black.  The obvious way this might happen is if newX and newY map to Y and X, instead of to X and Y as they should; then unless the array is square, one of them will go out of range.  Check if the indexing of 1 and 2 is backwards.

Comment: Think I still need a bit more to repro your output - please update the original question to show how you are reading in the picture file, and how you are viewing it to produce the images you linked.

Comment: I don't have imshow, but I'm not able to issues you're seeing using other visualization tools.  The function as written looks fine to me.  Not sure what errors could be causing what you're seeing, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`imresize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imresize.html) it can be easily achieved

```
pic_new = imresize( pic, newSize, 'bicubic' );
```

Where `newSize` is the new size of the image (height and width). The new aspect ratio can be arbitrary and does not have to be the same as the aspect ratio of the new image.

For example, shrinking an image by 1/2 along the rows and leaving number of columns unchanged:

```
[nCol nRows] = size( pic(:,:,1) );
pic_new = imresize( pic, [nCols round( nRows/2 ) ], 'bicubic' );
```

Comment: I'm aware that the OP might not have the image processing toolbox and thus does not have access to `imresize`. However, for future reference I believe it is best to leave this `imresize` option here.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `imresize`

Comment: @Shai Why do you think it is better to leave `imresize` out?

Comment: @Masi I do not think it is better to leave `imresize` out: I think it is better to leave the `imresize` answer in this thread despite the OP requirement not to use `imresize`.

Comment: Actually, I am not so sure anymore. I think you cannot return the original image from the imageResized. Right? There is no bijection from `imresize` output to the original image. Even the colormap is charged.